# Flutter Plugin access native objects

Tags: java, flutter, dart, plugins, native

I'm developing a Flutter plugin to implements an iOS SDK and an Android SDK in Flutter. In both native SDKs, there is an object called Peripheral, which is a complexe object extending and implementing other objects. If I want to use theses Objects, do I have to implement them in Flutter too ? Or can I just create an manipulate instances of those objects from dart.

Right now, I'm trying to manipulate instances by have a PeripheralObject that calls a function in constructor that will create an instance in native Java (for Android) of a peripheral, place it in a hash map, and return it's memory adress to dart. In dart, I keep the memory adress of the Java object and when I call a function, like `getName`, I pass to the method channel the java memory adress and with that, I can retrieve from the map my instance of the native object, call the method and send back the answer. Is it a good way of resolving the problem or is there other better way to do so ?

Here is my dart object:

```dart
class Peripheral {
  late String _objectReference;
  late String _localName, _uuid;

  Peripheral({required String localName, required String uuid}) {
    _uuid = uuid;
    _localName = localName;
    _newPeripheralInstance(localName, uuid);
  }


  Future<void> _newPeripheralInstance(String localName, String uuid) async {
    _objectReference = (await PeripheralPlatform.instance.newPeripheralInstance(localName, uuid))!;
    return;
  }

  String get objectReference => _objectReference;

  Future<String?> getModelName() async {
    return PeripheralPlatform.instance.getModelName(_objectReference);
  }

  Future<String?> getUuid() async {
    return PeripheralPlatform.instance.getUuid(_objectReference);
  }
}
```

Here is my Dart Method Channel :

```dart
class MethodChannelPeripheral extends PeripheralPlatform {
  /// The method channel used to interact with the native platform.
  @visibleForTesting
  final methodChannel = const MethodChannel('channel');

  @override
  Future<String?> newPeripheralInstance(String localName, String uuid) async {
    String? instance = await methodChannel.invokeMethod<String>('Peripheral-newPeripheralInstance',  <String, String>{
      'localName': localName,
      'uuid': uuid
    });
    return instance;
  }

  @override
  Future<String?> getModelName(String peripheralReference) {
    return methodChannel.invokeMethod<String>('Peripheral-getModelName', <String, String>{
      'peripheralReference': peripheralReference
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<String?> getUuid(String peripheralReference) {
    return methodChannel.invokeMethod<String>('Peripheral-getUuid', <String, String>{
      'peripheralReference': peripheralReference
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my Android Java file :

```java
public class PluginPeripheral {
  private static Map<String, Peripheral> peripheralMap = new HashMap<>();

  public static void handleMethodCall(String method, MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    method = method.replace("Peripheral-", "");
    switch (method) {
      case "newPeripheralInstance":
        newPeripheralInstance(call, result);
        break;
      case "getModelName":
        getModelName(call, result);
        break;
      case "getUuid":
        getUuid(call, result);
        break;
      default:
        result.notImplemented();
        break;
    }
  }

  private static void newPeripheralInstance(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (call.hasArgument("uuid") && call.hasArgument("localName")) {
      String uuid = call.argument("uuid");
      String localName = call.argument("localName");
      if (localName == null || uuid == null) {
        result.error("Missing argument", "Missing argument 'uuid' or 'localName'", null);
        return;
      }
      Peripheral peripheral = new Peripheral(localName, uuid);
      peripheralMap.put(peripheral.toString(), peripheral);
      result.success(peripheral.toString());
    }
  }

  private static void getModelName(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (call.hasArgument("peripheralReference")) {
      String peripheralString = call.argument("peripheralReference");
      if (peripheralString == null) {
        result.error("Missing argument", "Missing argument 'peripheral'", null);
        return;
      }
      Peripheral peripheral = peripheralMap.get(peripheralString);
      if (peripheral == null) {
        result.error("Invalid peripheral", "Invalid peripheral", null);
        return;
      }
      result.success(peripheral.getModelName());
    } else {
      result.error("Missing argument", "Missing argument 'peripheralReference'", null);
    }
  }

  private static void getUuid(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (call.hasArgument("peripheralReference")) {
      String peripheralString = call.argument("peripheralReference");
      if (peripheralString == null) {
        result.error("Missing argument", "Missing argument 'peripheral'", null);
        return;
      }
      Peripheral peripheral = peripheralMap.get(peripheralString);
      if (peripheral == null) {
        result.error("Invalid peripheral", "Invalid peripheral", null);
        return;
      }
      result.success(peripheral.getUuid());
    } else {
      result.error("Missing argument", "Missing argument 'peripheralReference'", null);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way is to convert an object to a map in Android and back to an object in Flutter. Something like this:

Flutter/Dart:

```
class Device {
  String? id;
  String? name;

...
  Device.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
  }
}

final map = await methodChannel.invokeMethod('requestDevice');
final device = Device.fromMap(map.cast<String, dynamic>());
```

Android/Kotlin:

```
data class Device(
    val id: String,
    val name: String?
) {

...
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "id" to id,
            "name" to name
        )
    }
}

override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
...
    result.success(device.toMap())
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I would need to re-implement the object in Dart and I don't want to do that since the object is very complicated and has a lot of functions. But Thanks !